# Are SIMD groups supported in Metal on iOS?

Tags: ios, gpgpu, metal

I can't figure out whether or not SIMD groups are supported on iOS.

[The Metal Shading Language Specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf) states at the time of writing on page 59, section 4.4.1:

> iOS: No support for SIMD-groups.

However, in Table 6.11., "SIMD-group functions in the Metal standard library", some SIMD-group functions are listed as supported on iOS. This is one of the ones I'd like to use:

> `T simd_shuffle_down(T data, ushort delta)`
>
> macOS: Since Metal 2.0.
>
> iOS: Since Metal 2.2.

Similarly, table Table 5.7., "Attributes for kernel function input arguments", states that some attributes are available:

> `threads_per_simdgroup`
>
> macOS: Since Metal 2.0.
>
> iOS: Since Metal 2.2.

So it's not clear from the documentation whether any SIMD group functionality is supposed to be supported. Using a function argument with the `threads_per_simdgroup` attribute in a compute kernel currently causes the run-time Metal compiler to crash on iPhone 7 and 8 (but not 11):

> Compiler failed with XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED

All devices tested with iOS 13.3. Metal language version was 2.2. Xcode version 11.3.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the claim that SIMD-groups are unsupported on iOS is either inaccurate, or not specific enough.

If you consult the [Metal Feature Set Tables](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Feature-Set-Tables.pdf) for Metal 2.2, you'll note that "SIMD-scoped permute operations" (`simd_broadcast`,
`simd_shuffle`, `simd_shuffle_up`, etc.) are supported on `MTLGPUFamilyApple6`, which includes devices with A13 processors. Hence why this works on iPhone 11.

The fact that using this attribute on unsupported devices causes a compiler crash is a bug, and I'd recommend that you [file feedback](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com).

Comment: warrenm, where are the "SIMD-scoped permute operations" listed?

Comment: The same table you referenced in section 6.8.2 of the language spec. I don't have another resource for this information.

Comment: OK. I think you're probably right, but we don't know for sure unless it's stated somewhere by Apple what the "SIMD-scoped permute operations" are. :)